# Change Gmail label once attachment is uploaded to drive

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

How can you remove the existing label "Global Alcohol" & add a "Global Processed" label to the email messages which have had the attachments uploaded to Google Drive using the following code? I must give credit to Cooper who answered my first question & helped me get the uploads working.

```js
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var userId = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var query = "label:Global Alcohol";
  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});//I assumed that this works
  res.messages.forEach(function(m){
    var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
    attA.forEach(function(a){
      var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyMMddHHmmss");
      folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName()+ts);
    });
  });
}
```

I have read the API documentation & can see that you need to use the following code to modify the Labels. However I am stuck with how to integrate it into the function above.

```js
function modifyMessage(userId, messageId, labelsToAdd, labelsToRemove, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.modify({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': messageId,
    'addLabelIds': labelsToAdd,
    'removeLabelIds': labelsToRemove
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the modification call, but the formatting is slightly off. The trick here is that you need to use the label IDs, so I wrote a new function `getLabelsByName()` that allows you to perform that lookup.

```
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var userId = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var query = "label:Global Alcohol";
  var labels = getLabelsByName(userId, ["Global Alcohol", "Global Processed"]);
  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});//I assumed that this works  
  res.messages.forEach(function(m){
    var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
    attA.forEach(function(a){
      var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyMMddHHmmss");
      folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName()+ts);
    });

    // Remove the old label & add the new one
    Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({
      addLabelIds: [labels["Global Processed"].id],
      removeLabelIds: [labels["Global Alcohol"].id]
    }, userId, m.id);
  });
}

/**
 * Lookup any number of labels by their name using the advanced Gmail service.
 * @param {String} userId - The user's email address or "me" to get your own
 * @param {String[]} labelNames - An array of labels names to search for
 * @returns {Label{}} - Map of labels identified by label name
 * https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels
 */
function getLabelsByName(userId, labelNames) {
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.list(userId);
  var selectedLabels = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
    var label = response.labels[i];
    if (labelNames.indexOf(label.name) != -1) {
      selectedLabels[label.name] = label;
    }
  }
  return selectedLabels;
}
```

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for the explanation & help. The only problem is that using the "message.getThread() method to change the labels results in unwanted emails from the same sender which are in different labels being processed. Gmail deems them to be part of the thread. So the method to change the labels needs to be via the message id's, not thread - as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

Comment: @BradLegassick Understood. In that case, you were on the right track to continue using the advanced gmail service. I've updated the answer.